# Do I get charged any fee if pay my Chase Amazon prime credit card bill from Bank of America?

Tags: credit-card

I have a bank account with Bank of America. I am planning to apply for the Amazon Prime rewards credit card by Chase. Do I get charged any fee if pay my Chase Amazon prime credit card bill with auto bank transfer from Bank of America?

Comment: No.  (I've paid a lot of credit cards "across banks", and never been charged such a fee.  In fact, I've never heard of such a thing.)

Comment: What would make you think you would?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco banks do it with ATM machines, so it's a somewhat reasonable question from someone who's only ever used ATM machines.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's what I said yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will not get charged a fee by either bank for paying your card off in this manner.

*Sometimes* there are extra perks for having a checking account and credit card with the same institution, but never a fee just for using different banks and paying between them.